# Changing color and shape of point in time series plot depending on value of different variable in r

Tags: r, time-series, timeserieschart, performanceanalytics

I have a time series which contains probabilities.  For simplicity, imagine each point represents my estimate as to whether it would rain in New York on a given day.  When I plot the time series, I want the symbol to be of pch=1 and the col="green" if I were correct and if I were wrong, I'd like to use pch=4 and col="red".

I've tried and failed with a couple of approaches. Mainly I am using the chart.TimeSeries function in PerformanceAnalytics.  I'm open to ideas.

I have tried plotting one series including vectors for pch and col to represent correct and incorrect.  I have tried plotting just the correct points and the using the points function to add the incorrect ones.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you provide examples of code what you've already tried? It will help other users to solve problem which you described.

Comment: Post code. Otherwise you are just asking us to go to the help pages and pull examples (from packages we do not have loaded). That's work you should be doing. Furthermore the term time series is ambiguous. There are several different classes of objects that might be "time series" and we should not need to guess.

Answer (score 0):

I will try to guess at what you are asking. First create a set of predictions for each day in some month and decide if your prediction was correct:

```
df <- data.frame(days = 1:31,
                 p_rain = runif(31),
                 correct = sample(c(TRUE,FALSE),31,T))
```

Now create your symbols and colors based on whether or not you were correct:

```
df$ppch <- 1 # the default
df$ppch[df$correct==FALSE] <- 4 # when you were wrong
```

Similarly,

```
df$pcolor <- as.character('green')
df$pcolor[df$correct==FALSE] <- 'red'
```

Now plot:

```
with(df, plot(days,p_rain,pch=ppch,col=pcolor))
```

[image]